# How do LinearGradient on text in flutter from topLeft to bottomRight?

Tags: flutter, text, gradient, linear-gradients

Hy everyone,

I need to know, how do I can create so a Gradient colors from topLeft to bottomRight withhin a shader in flutter like in this image example?

[image]

I tried with this mini shader code to do this, but it still doesn't working for me.

```
final Shader linearGradient = LinearGradient(
  colors: gradientColors,
).createShader(
  Rect.fromCircle(
    center: Offset(fontSize, -200),
    radius: fontSize / 3,
  ),
);
```

Could anybody have a ideea, how can this be created? Or it's not impossible right now in Flutter ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `begin` and `end` properties of `LinearGradient`?

```
final Shader linearGradient = LinearGradient(
  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
  colors: gradientColors,
).createShader(
  Rect.fromCircle(
    center: Offset(fontSize, -200), 
    radius: fontSize / 3,
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(                                       
        gradient: LinearGradient(
           begin:Alignment.topLeft,
           end:Alignment.bottomRight,
             colors: [Colors.blue[800],
                 Colors.blue[200]
        ]),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to format code into codeblocks, so it is easier to read.

Comment: FYI: I've edited your answer to include @DapperDuck's correct recommendation to use code formatting. Please review my edit so that you can correctly format your contributions in the future.